# I have downloaded node as well as npm , and it is well installed in the system , but npm is still not working

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-package

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.2.4

This is what cmd is showing when i do npm -v, please can anybody help me , i have been not able to solve this issue a thousand times even after reinstalling and setting variables again and again

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.2.4

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue related to ComSpec where it had been set for javajdk and not for cmd.exe , so I formatted the ComSpec variable and now npm is working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).